# Upload a file using Symfony2 and a simple form

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to upload a file in my symfony2 project by using a simple Form.
I did read the official doc of symfony but Id want only move my file to directory and update a field in a db table (called user) not create an entity for the file. I use an example I succeed to upload but in .tmp extension (ex. phpXXX.tmp). Any Ideas please.

**here my code :**

*Document.php:*

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


class Document
{

    private $file;

    private $subDir;

    private $filePersistencePath;

    /** @var string */
    protected static $uploadDirectory = '%kernel.root_dir%/../styles/images';

    static public function setUploadDirectory($dir)
    {
        self::$uploadDirectory = $dir;
    }

    static public function getUploadDirectory()
    {
        if (self::$uploadDirectory === null) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Trying to access upload directory for profile files");
        }
        return self::$uploadDirectory;
    }
    public function setSubDirectory($dir)
    {
         $this->subDir = $dir;
    }

    public function getSubDirectory()
    {
        if ($this->subDir === null) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Trying to access sub directory for profile files");
        }
        return $this->subDir;
    }


    public function setFile(File $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return new File(self::getUploadDirectory() . "/" . $this->filePersistencePath);
    }

     public function getOriginalFileName()
    {
        return $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    public function getFilePersistencePath()
    {
        return $this->filePersistencePath;
    }

    public function processFile()
    {
        if (! ($this->file instanceof UploadedFile) ) {
            return false;
        }
        $uploadFileMover = new UploadFileMover();
        $this->filePersistencePath = $uploadFileMover->moveUploadedFile($this->file, self::getUploadDirectory(),$this->subDir);
    }
}
```

*UploadFileMover*

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

    class UploadFileMover {

        public function moveUploadedFile(UploadedFile $file, $uploadBasePath, $relativePath) {
            $originalName = $file->getFilename();
            // use filemtime() to have a more determenistic way to determine the subpath, otherwise its hard to test.
            // $relativePath = date('Y-m', filemtime($file->getPath()));
            $targetFileName = $relativePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $originalName;
            $targetFilePath = $uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $targetFileName;
            $ext = $file->getExtension();
            $i = 1;
            while (file_exists($targetFilePath) && md5_file($file->getPath()) != md5_file($targetFilePath)) {
                if ($ext) {
                    $prev = $i == 1 ? "" : $i;
                    $targetFilePath = $targetFilePath . str_replace($prev . $ext, $i++ . $ext, $targetFilePath);
                } else {
                    $targetFilePath = $targetFilePath . $i++;
                }
            }
            $targetDir = $uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $relativePath;
            if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
                $ret = mkdir($targetDir, umask(), true);
                if (!$ret) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException("Could not create target directory to move temporary file into.");
                }
            }
            $file->move($targetDir, basename($targetFilePath));

            return str_replace($uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $targetFilePath);
        }

    }

controller : 

public function uploadImgAction(Request $req) {
        if ($req->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $status = 'success';
            $uploadedURL = '';
            $message = 'Image modifiée';

            $image = $req->files->get('fileselect');

            if (($image instanceof UploadedFile) && ($image->getError() == '0')) {
                if ($image->getSize() < 2000000) {
                     $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $name_array = explode('.', $originalName);
                    $file_type = $name_array[sizeof($name_array) - 1];
                    $valid_filetypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png');
                    if (in_array(strtolower($file_type), $valid_filetypes)) {
                        //télécharegement du fichier
                        //Start Uploading File

                      $document = new Document();
                      $document->setFile($image);
                      $document->setSubDirectory('uploads');
                      $document->processFile();
                      $uploadedURL=$uploadedURL = $document->getUploadDirectory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $document->getSubDirectory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $image->getBasename();
                   } else {
                        $status = 'echoue';
                        $message = 'Seuls les extensions png, jpg, jpeg et bmp sont acceptées';
                    }
                } else {
                    $status = 'echoue';
                    $message = 'La taille du fichier dépasse 2MB';
                }
            } else {
                $status = 'echoue';
                $message = 'Une erreur de télechargement';
            }

             return $this->render('PIRecrutementBundle:xx:xxx.html.twig');
            //return new Response($uploadedUrl);
        } else {
            return $this->render('xxxBundle:xx:xxx.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check what `$file->getFilename();` is returning? Is it name.ext or just name? If it's just name you need to get also extension this way: `$file->getFilename();`

Comment: It returns something like that : phpAD84.tmp

Comment: So then as far as I see from your code you need to pass `$image->getClientOriginalName()` into  method `moveUploadedFile` because your method has only information about uploaded file where you have only tmp name and extensions. It works similar like in `upload()` action in documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as [Tomasz Turkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604320/tomasz-turkowski) said the solution is to change the base-name of the file by its real name using $file->getClientOriginalName( in class UploadFileMover.

```
class UploadFileMover {

public function moveUploadedFile(UploadedFile $file, $uploadBasePath, $relativePath) 
{
   // $originalName = $file->getFilename();
      $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        // use filemtime() to have a more determenistic
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything like .tmp to some other extention or the original name, you can still store the same obtained path in DB. I think you can write a query to store the path in DB after this statement in your controller

```
$uploadedURL=$uploadedURL = $document->getUploadDirectory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $document->getSubDirectory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $image->getBasename();
```

By using the variable `$uploadURL` like

```
{

//in your methodAction

"Update [YOUR TABLE] SET [PATHcolomn]=".$uploadURL." WHERE USERid=".$user->getUid()." "

$path= "SELECT [PATHcolomN] FROM [YOUR TABLE] WHERE USERid=".$user->getUid()." "

$this->data['path']=$path;

return $this->data;


}
```

After Updating, you can fetch this path in the place of `<img src= {{ path }} >`